# Extend Window interface in base package, import into a consuming package

Tags: typescript, types

I'm feeling pretty silly, but all I want to do is extend the Window interface in one package, and have that type definition be available in a consuming package.

In package A, I can define a file like:

```
// src/typings/global.d.ts

declare global {
  interface MyCustomDataInterface {
    // ...
  }
  interface Window {
    myCustomData: MyCustomDataInterface;
  }
}

export {};
```

Now, in package B, I add package A as a dependency.  I want to be able to type "window." in a source file in package B and see that `myCustomData` is available on the Window object.  I'm sure there's some configuration I'm missing, but haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Reference the global augmentation in the entry point(s) of PackageA using a side effecting import clause `// in A import "./typings/global";`. Then PackageB will transitively acquire the augmentation.

Comment: In package A, it looks like if I define the file in "src/@types/global.d.ts" instead, I can access `window.myCustomData` in other package A source files without explicitly importing the global file.  That's why I thought there was a way in package B's configuration to do the same.

Comment: There is a way.